Customizing Apple Smart Banner
I recently integrated the Apple Smart App Banner into my website using the following meta tag:
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=1528595354, app-argument=https://tlfapparel.com" />
The banner is working as expected: when a user doesn’t have the app, it prompts them to download it, and when the user has the app, it opens the app. However, I’ve noticed that other sites, like Alo Yoga, have a customized background and a feature where, if the user already has the app downloaded, the banner does not display the "X" button to dismiss it. Instead, it only shows the option to open the app. I would like to accomplish this on my site.
Example of Aloyoga
I looked at the Apple documentation, and it seems like the Smart App Banner isn’t customizable. I also tried detecting if the user has the app downloaded, but I couldn’t find a way to do this without requiring user interaction with the banner
